# Is it Possible to access SDK From Static Resource?

Tags: apex, class, static-resources, sdk

If I have a SDK in .jar file can I upload it to Static Resource and call it in Apex Classes.
As per Documentation it says I can able to call ".css" , ".Js" , ".Jar" Files in VF Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute `.jar` file but its not about executing class object and using its instance in Apex code. You can **not** do this.

`.jar` files are used to execute java application as `applet`. You can execute applet in Visualforce page.

Ex:

```
<applet width="200" height="200" archive="{!$Resource.MyAppletJarFile}" code="com.MyApplet.SubmitQuoteApplet" />
```

Comment: So If I Have to use the SDK what should I Do ? Like in IDE where I can Import Library's in a Project.

Comment: Every SDK comes with a documentation to setup in Salesforce. Ex: Amazon AWS SDK comes as an install package and twilio SDK required ANT to deploy in organisation. @user40138